# Xcart shipping cost issue

Tags: x-cart

I want to know that the field for checkbox labeled as "Use the dimensions of this product for shipping cost calculation" when adding product in backend is where situated in database(ie. table name and field name) xcart?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about provider shipping rates, then table name is xcart_shipping_rates,

and if you are asking about calculation while adding new product then as i worked in x-cart it was just j javascript which is counting ct commisions. based on product weight, price and free shipping as Y or N. it will be found in skin/common_files/main/product_details.tpl

Comment: if I checked this checbox then where the value is stored as y or n?

Comment: it will be stored in xcart_products as free_shipping.. it will be stored as Y or N

Comment: No free_shipping is different. Its only asking to take preference of dimension or not when calculating shipping?

Comment: dimentions are just used to get that if provider wants to pack product in box or not.. if yes then click on include dimentions if you will not include it it's value will be 0. and if you are asking about the calculations then it will be done on product real price, weight and free shipping.

Comment: free shipping is drop down where it is check box

Comment: tell me what you actually wants to do...

Comment: and yes... shipping charge will be calculated on based of product weight.

Comment: you mean there is no field for this checkbox in db and we need to change tpl file if we by default want to change the checkbox unchecked. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I want to uncheck this box by default.

Comment: okh. so all you have to do is. find product details page as i given path in the answer. and change that checkbox to input type hidden. and set the value of it same as checkbox&#39;s value. and it&#39;s done. just set it's value as N.